# Given a symmetric bilinear form g, prove that every vector can be written as $ v=\sum_{i j} g^{i j} g\left(v, e_i\right) e_j, $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $(V, g)$ be an euclidean vector space and $\left(e_i\right)_i$ a basis for $V$ (not necessarily orthogonal) such that $\left\|e_i\right\|^2=g\left(e_i, e_i\right)=1$ for every $i=1, \ldots, n$. Prove that every vector $v \in V$ can be written locally (a.k.a. in coordinates) as
$$
v=\sum_{i j} g^{i j} g\left(v, e_i\right) e_j,
$$
where $g^{i j}$ denotes the coefficient of the inverse of the matrix $\left(g_{i j}\right)$.

Note that g is not the standard inner product but it is given by some positive (semi)definite matrix, so it isn't too far away from the standard inner product.

The problem I am running into right now is that we can express $v$ as linear combinations of the basis vectors, but I can't get the coefficients in terms of the matrix $g$ and I am not sure how to get the inverse matrix to show up or why it even shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We still have $v=\sum_{i} v^i e_i$ and we're solving for the vector of coordinates $V_i = v^i.$ We know the (symmetric pos. def.) "metrics" matrix $G_{i,j}=\langle e_i, e_j\rangle\equiv g(e_i,e_j)$ and the "projections" vector $W_j = \langle v, e_j\rangle \equiv g(v,e_j)$ for a given $v$. (I'd prefer it to be $g(e_j,v)$)

Let's take the inner product of the both sides of the $v=\sum_{i} v^i e_i$ with all $e_j$ and write the system of equations in matrix form as $W=G^TV$. We can invert a pos. def. $G$ and solve for $V=G^{-1}W$ or $V_i=\sum_{j}G^{-1}_{ij}W_j$. Plug this back into the original $v=\sum_i v^i e_i$ if you like and rewrite in your notation.